# How to get onChildClick, groupPosition and childPosition from ExpandableListView in android?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I'm really unsure as of how to get the groupPosition and the childPosition from the ExpandableListView. I tried using a switch and case, but that doesn't work it doesn't seem to recognize the groupPosition. So how can I get the groupPosition and childPosition?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set up our adapter
    mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter();
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView());

    getExpandableListView().setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener()
    {
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
        {
            switch(groupPosition & childPosition)
            {
            case 2 & 2:
                Intent asariIntent = new Intent(Codex.this, CodexAsari.class);
                Codex.this.startActivity(asariIntent);
                break;

            case 1 & 0:
                Intent protheanIntent = new Intent(Codex.this, CodexProthean.class);
                Codex.this.startActivity(protheanIntent);
                break;

            case 1 & 1:
                Intent rachniIntent = new Intent(Codex.this, CodexRachni.class);
                Codex.this.startActivity(rachniIntent);
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Sample menu");
    menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Sample action");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    String title = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();

    int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);
    if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
        int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition); 
        int childPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition); 
        Toast.makeText(this, title + ": Child " + childPos + " clicked in group " + groupPos,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    } else if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
        int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition); 
        Toast.makeText(this, title + ": Group " + groupPos + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
    public String[] groups = { "Aliens: Council Races", "Aliens: Extinct Races", "Aliens: Non-Council Races", "Aliens: Non-Sapient Creatures", "Citadel and Galactic Government", "Humanity and the Systems Alliance", "Known Associates" };
    private String[][] children = {
            { "Asari", "Salarians", "Turians" },
            { "Protheans", "Rachni" },
            { "Batarians", "Collectors", "Drell", "Elcor", "Geth", "Hanar", "Keepers", "Krogan", "Praetorians", "Quarians",
                "Reapers", "Reapers: Indoctrination", "Sovereign", "Volus", "Vorcha" },
            { "Husks", "Thresher Maws", "Varren" },
            { "Citadel", "Citadel Council", "Citadel Space", "Spectres" },
            { "Councilor Donnel Udina: Anderson Chosen Councilor", "Councilor Donnel Udina:  Undina Chosen Councilor", "Earth: Mass Effect", "Earth: Mass Effect 3", "First Contact War", "Systems Alliance", "Rise of the Alliance: Renegade", "Rise of the Alliance: Paragon" },
            { "Steven Hackett", "David Anderson", "Udina Chosen Councilor", "Dr. Liara T'Soni", "EDI", "Garrus Vakarian", "Kaidan Alenko", "Ashley Williams", "Tali'Zorah", "Dr. Mordin Solus", "Jacob Taylor", "Jeff 'Joker' Moreau", "Miranda Lawson", "Dr. Karin Chakwas" }
    };

    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return children[groupPosition].length;
    }

    public TextView getGenericView() {
        AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 64);

        TextView textView = new TextView(Codex.this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
        textView.setPadding(36, 0, 0, 0);
        return textView;
    }

    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView = getGenericView();
        textView.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());
        return textView;
    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups[groupPosition];
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.length;
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView = getGenericView();
        textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
        return textView;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }



}

public int childPosition()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I gotta say, i've never seen a case statement looking like that. Perhaps you could try the following and see if you get any different results:

```
getExpandableListView().setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        switch(groupPosition) {
        case 1: 
            switch (childPosition) {
            case 0: 
                Intent protheanIntent = new Intent(Codex.this, CodexProthean.class);
                Codex.this.startActivity(protheanIntent);
                break;              
            case 1:
                Intent rachniIntent = new Intent(Codex.this, CodexRachni.class);
                Codex.this.startActivity(rachniIntent);
                break;
            }
        case 2:
            switch (childPosition) {
            case 2: 
                Intent asariIntent = new Intent(Codex.this, CodexAsari.class);
                Codex.this.startActivity(asariIntent);
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding `getChildView()` in your `MyExpandableListAdapter` class. `getChildView` gets called whenever a child is touched on (or when its checkbox is checked or unchecked--I don't remember which, or if there's a difference). Within that method you have access to groupPosition and childPosition. See [Working with children in ExpandableListActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741671/working-with-children-in-expandablelistactivity) for more information.